# Why modal doesn't open if i don't use renderPage() function on console?

Tags: javascript, html, console, render

I try to display product modal to user can customize product. Some product modals are opening but I didn't understand why another products modal doesn't open.

If I write renderPage() function on console that doesn't open product modal, modal will open.
For this I added renderPage() function to footer. But that's not work.

Like that

```
<script defer>
    window.onload = function () { // same as window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            renderPage();
    };
</script>
```

When I click this button, modal doesn't open.

[image]

But if I write renderPage on console and click button again, modal will be opened.

[image]

Comment: What is `renderPage`?  I assume your using some library that creates a mount point for the dialog, so if you don't call rendePager then there is no mount point for it.  But it's only an assumption as there is not enough detail here to know for sure.

Comment: We use a library and renderPage function is in the that library.

Comment: The simplest place to put loading scripts is just before your closing body tag.

Comment: Also I would check your console for errors, you might be just having loading / executing order issues, eg. I noticed you have used defer for this script, if you did the same for some of its dependencies you might get errors.